# How to remove characters from a variable in your dataset in R?

Tags: r, dataset, character

I have dataset consisting of daily data in the format YYMMDD such as `20090101, 20090102, 20090103`.

I want to remove the years `2009, 2010, 2011, ..., 2019`, so that each date looks like the following: `0101, 0102, 0103`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution based in the tidyverse.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = str_sub(date, -4))

#   date 
#   <chr>
# 1 0101 
# 2 0201 
# 3 0301
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("20090101", "20200201", "20120301")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @Andrei: You are very welcome. If the solution closes the case for you, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing that rjen answered, but using base R:

```
df = substr(df,5,8)
```